# Minikube start automatically selects hyperkit as driver

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

I installed `minikube` and `Virtualbox` on OS X and was working fine until I executed

`minikube delete`

After that I tried

`minikube start`

and got the following

> minikube v1.5.2 on Darwin 10.15.1
>
> ✨  Automatically selected the 'hyperkit' driver (alternates: [virtualbox])
>
> The 'hyperkit' driver requires elevated permissions. The following commands will be executed:
>
> ...

I do not want to use a different driver, why is this happening? I reinstalled minikube but the problem persisted. I could set which driver to use with:

`minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`

But I would rather have the default behavior after a fresh install. How can I set the default driver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After googling a bit I found how to do it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/637)

`minikube config set vm-driver virtualbox`

This command output is

> ⚠️  These changes will take effect upon a minikube delete and then a minikube start

So make sure to run

`minikube delete`

and

`minikube start`